# System.currentTimeMillis() vs. new Date() vs. Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

Tags: java, performance, date, time, calendar

In Java, what are the performance and resource implications of using

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

vs.

```
new Date()
```

vs.

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

As I understand it, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the most efficient. However, in most applications, that long value would need to be converted to a Date or some similar object to do anything meaningful to humans.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is obviously the most **efficient** since it does not even create an object, but `new Date()` is really just a thin wrapper about a long, so it is not far behind. `Calendar`, on the other hand, is relatively slow and very complex, since it has to deal with the considerably complexity and all the oddities that are inherent to dates and times (leap years, daylight savings, timezones, etc.).

It's generally a good idea to deal only with long timestamps or `Date` objects within your application, and only use `Calendar` when you actually need to perform date/time calculations, or to format dates for displaying them to the user. If you have to do a lot of this, using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is probably a good idea, for the cleaner interface and better performance.

Comment: What is the difference between timestamp and currentMillis?

Comment: @pinkpanther: "timestamp" is normally used to describe an integer/long that describes a point in time when interpreted as the seconds or milliseconds since an "epoch start". In other words, currentTimeMillis() returns a timestamp.

Answer (score 46):

Looking at the JDK, innermost constructor for `Calendar.getInstance()` has this:

```
public GregorianCalendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale) {
    super(zone, aLocale);
    gdate = (BaseCalendar.Date) gcal.newCalendarDate(zone);
    setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

so it already automatically does what you suggest. Date's default constructor holds this:

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

So there really isn't need to get system time specifically unless you want to do some math with it before creating your Calendar/Date object with it. Also I do have to recommend [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to use as replacement for Java's own calendar/date classes if your purpose is to work with date calculations a lot.

Answer (score 23):

If you're USING a date then I strongly advise that you use jodatime, http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/. Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` for fields that *are* dates sounds like a very bad idea because you'll end up with a lot of useless code.

Both date and calendar are seriously borked, and Calendar is definitely the worst performer of them all.

I'd advise you to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` when you are actually operating with milliseconds, for instance like this

```
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    .... do something ...
 long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() -start;
```

Comment: I wanted to comment on this because your example is exactly one of the things you should *NOT* use System.currentTimeMillis() for; it is not a monotonic clock source, so you cannot reliably calculate elapsed time with it. If the system clock is changed while the code you are timing is executing, you will get weird (e.g. negative) results.
In stead use System.nanoTime(), which *is* monotonic *if* the underlying system supports such a clock source (see http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6458294 )

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis  itself is not affected by time zone. Changing system time will affect System.nanotime in the same way as System.currentTimeMillis

Comment: @Viktor that is incorrect, `nanoTime()` is an always increasing counter, it will never return a value less than the last time called in this JVM instance. `currentTimeMillis()` can return a value less than the last time called, due to the system time being changed, e.g. NTP clock sync.

Answer (score 15):

On my machine I tried check it. My result:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime() (*1000000 times) = 402ms
new Date().getTime(); (*1000000 times) = 18ms
System.currentTimeMillis() (*1000000 times) = 16ms
```

Don't forget about GC (if you use `Calendar.getInstance()` or `new Date()`)

Comment: wonder if there will be any difference if many threads call the same in between other processing

Answer (score 12):

I prefer using the value returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()` for all kinds of calculations and only use `Calendar` or `Date` if I need to really display a value that is read by humans. This will also prevent 99% of your daylight-saving-time bugs. :)

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your application, you may want to consider using `System.nanoTime()` instead.

Comment: Why, his question was about resources and performance, nanoTime() uses more resources

Comment: I mentioned it because it's an option that no one else suggested.  The poster did not specify a platform.  SDN bug 6876279 suggests that currentTimeMillis() and nanoTime() take about the same in some JDK versions.  The poster also did not specify their accuracy needs, for which the original list may be inadequate.

Comment: Late as this may be, all the examples in the question have an absolute notion of what time it is eg. 1,348,770,313,071 millis since the start of the Unix epoch. The time that `nanoTime` returns is relative (usually to the start of the program) and would be nonsense if you tried to turn it into a date.

Comment: yes but you could store currentTimeilli and nano in some static code on program start, then use those as offsets to get an accurate nano from milli using a double var = currentTimeStart - nanoTimeStart + nanoTimeNow

Answer (score 3):

I tried this:

```
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            new Date().getTime();
        }
        long result = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;

        System.out.println("Date(): " + result);

        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        result = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;

        System.out.println("currentTimeMillis(): " + result);
```

And result was:

Date(): 199

currentTimeMillis(): 3

Comment: This is a micro benchmark and you should be careful to trust the results you get. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java.

Comment: This benchmark is not significative, or better, it shows that operating system under Java does matter. I ran the same benchmark in a loop dozen of times (moving initialization of "now" and "result" out of the loop), and I had cute differences at each run: Date() : 322 to 330; currentTimeMillis(): 319 to 322. On some other runs I had  Date() : 312 to 318; currentTimeMillis(): 324 to 335. So, IMHO they are quite equivalent, on real cases (also looking at the source of Date). JFYI, I used Java7 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is obviously the fastest because it's only one method call and no garbage collector is required.

Comment: Your answer holds no value since it is just a subset of the previously approved answer. You should try not to answer in this manner, especially not considering it is a very old question with a already existing quality answer.

Comment: Secondly, garbage collector is not required for short term objects in Eden space anyway.