# Java EE/Java Browser Security

Tags: java, tomcat, https

I have a problem with my Java EE (Tomcat) java based web application.

- user logs in to website
- user viewing page a ssl page in our web site
- user logs off, session invalidated
- user gets redirected to login page (ssl)
- user hits the back button and is able to get to the page in step 2.

How is this avoidable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Cache-Control` header on those pages to

```
no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

(also `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, `Pragma`)

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876250/tomcat-cache-control) for how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The user is only recieving a cached copy of the logged in page. If they try to do anything on that page, they will find the session has ended.

One possible method of stopping this (although it may not be the best) is to add some JS to each page that will redirect the user to the log-in page if the session has ended.