# Errror in Proxy server when caching HTML page

Tags: struts2, spring-security, tomcat7, cache-control, proxy-server

### **Problem:**

1. UserA and UserB are in a network with server proxy.
2. UserA opens page "www.myapp.com/initPage.htm".
3. If UserB opens the same page, then he will see the page with information from UserA.
4. For the proxy server is the same page so it returns the information it has cached.

### **More Info:**

1. Each user has different JSESSIONID and stored in the attribute set-cookie of the header response.
2. The URL is the same for the two users but the information depends on the JSESSIONID.
3. The proxy server don't stores the JSON calls only HTML pages.
4. I tried to solve the problem with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997498) but did not work.

### Architecture:

1. My application is implemented with Spring Security 3.1 and Struts2.
2. Work on Apache2 server, which is connected to a Tomcat7 through mod_jk module and configured with "workers.properties" file.

How I can tell the proxy server will never save the HTML page?

Best regards and thanks.

Comment: Did you check at the proxy server why it caches the page, also what is the proxy server used in the infrastructure?

Comment: I have no more information on the proxy server and I can not change it because it is in the network of a client that uses the application, is external to the web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997498) worked but adding the filter in the first position in the web.xml.

Best regards and thanks.