# How to set Cache Control to no-cache in Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, caching, tomcat7, cache-control, no-cache

I am trying to set the `Cache Control` for Tomcat 7 to the `no-cache` option.

I have tried to use the `ExpiresFilter` in my `web.xml` as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 0 seconds</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 0 seconds</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 0 seconds</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresDefault</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 0 seconds</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

However when I read my response headers all I get is:

`Cache-Control:max-age=0`

and not `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

How can I set my Tomcat server to specify `Cache-Control: no-cache` only through configuration files?

Comment: From the documentation: To modify Cache-Control directives other than max-age (see RFC 2616 section 14.9), you can use other servlet filters or Apache Httpd mod_headers module.

Comment: @FedericoSierra do you know what other servlet filters they are referring to? I didn't see any in the documentation that would work or do you have to make your own?

Comment: No, you can add a custom servlet (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876250/tomcat-cache-control) or put a reverse proxy to manipulate the headers (eg: apache, nginx, etc)

Comment: @FedericoSierra not a big deal for intermediate-to-senior level developers to add this functionality manually, but it's quite strange that in 2017 Tomcat doesn't provide this functionality out-of-the-box

Comment: @Yura Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set 'Cache-Control: no-cache' you will have to create a Custom filter, the ExpiresFilter is used to add 'Expires' and 'Cache-Control: max-age=' headers to HTTP response according to its 'Content-Type' and will not help in setting 'no-cache'

Follow the below steps

1. A custom filter should be written in order to set the headers, Package the filter inside a .jar
2. Put the .jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib
3. Verify there are no 'ClassNotFoundException' once you add the jar in $CATALINA_HOME/lib

```
    package nocache;
    
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    
    public class CacheFilter implements Filter { 
    
        @Override 
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, 
                             FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
    
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse; 
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response); 
        } 
    }
```

4. Add the below content to the $CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml file

Sample web.xml deployment descriptor snippet

---

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>nocache.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

5. Access the application and checkout the response headers.