# How to add Cache-Control, Pragma and expires in Tomcat 8.5 web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, cache-control, pragma

I need to add

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0

This needs to be added in the web.xml for all APIs. The Expires Filter of Apache doesn't seem to work for this. Are there any other filters that I can use? I also don't think Apache httpd headers will work in web.xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat: Cache-Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876250/tomcat-cache-control)

Comment: Already seen that. Didn't find any relevant solution. Decided to add custom response headers and see if it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to do it by adding custom headers using a response header filter that I found on Github

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: provide more information, else this thing can be closed