# The way to get day of week, pacific time

Tags: java

I need to write a method to get day of week (pacific time) for current time. Is the following code correct?

```
static Calendar s_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
static {
    s_calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
}

public static int getDayOfWeek() {
    s_calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return s_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"),
    Locale.US);
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: I created a static Calendar object, because I think it may be expensive to create it at every method call.

Comment: Depends on your use case whether or not optimizing the Calendar creation matters. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime

Answer (score 0):

System.currentTimeMillis() returns the millis in UTC.
Convert it before you call get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

Comment: I made a test. I didn't see any issue without converting it.
Java doc specified that "setTimeInMillis(long millis): millis - the new time in UTC milliseconds from the epoch." http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis(long)