# How get date in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to get a getTime() method for my chart.. I don't know how get it really. I need something that shows me the date in format for example `MMM dd h.m`. Can anyone show me some methods? Thank you

Comment: A search on `java date format` turns about 128,000,000 results, including http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html#formatdata and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateintro.html and http://java67.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html and http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/

Comment: [this shows how to get the date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java)... [this shows how to get a specific format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)... also, if the "chart" stuff is relevant, you might want to expand on what you mean by that. Are you using any 3rd party libraries etc.

Comment: yeah i'm using GraphView library..

Comment: @David_D: (as I can't comment on that deleted answer anymore) Firstly, Android is not a language. Secondly, you can actually [write android apps with C#](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid), so it should be clarified in your question (which it currently is via a java tag)

Comment: Okok..sorry and thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get current date in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654990/how-can-i-get-current-date-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can use as below :

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd hh.mm");
dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
Date today = new Date();
String s = dateFormatter.format(today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Date cDate = new Date();
 String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(cDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` for date and time formate. i.e.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that android application development is done in Java.

You can use: [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Output:

```
Thu Aug 29 13:03:34 GMT 2013
```

Use the API to get the format you want.