# Current Date Time in " YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM.000z" (ISO 8601) format in Android

Tags: java, android, iso8601

Hello i am very new to android Development , working on a Android Code right now ,I need to Get the current date and time in this Format

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM.000z
```

For Example 
2013-11-26T03:16:00.000Z

Any Help will be really Appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation readily available for Android's SimpleDateFormat class at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Also appears to have been [answered before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654990/how-can-i-get-current-date-in-android) Among other places.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

You are asking for the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format set to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone.

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2018-01-25T22:50:24.702645Z

## java.time

The java.time classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing or generating strings.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Get the current moment in UTC:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format:

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generate string in standard format.
```

Going the other direction, parsing such a string.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2013-11-26T03:16:00.000Z" );
```

Search Stack Overflow for much discussion of java.time classes such as `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `OffsetDateTime`.

## Joda-Time

Update: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

ISO 8601 formats are the default for the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

```java
System.out.println( "Now: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime( org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
Now: 2013-11-26T20:25:12.014Z
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat sd= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`