# how to set date in textview automatic - android

Tags: android, datetime

i trying to add date to textview automatic but its give me a old date like 1/1/1970
not the current date

here is the code

```
     private long date;
    private DateFormat format;
String currentDateandTime;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SimpleDateFormat datef = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String currentDateandTime = datef.format(new Date(date));

    TextView set_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_date);
    Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
    try {  
        set_date.setText(format.format(new Date(date)));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

so how can i make this code load the current date of the device not this old date ?

Comment: Have you tried this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654990/how-can-i-get-current-date-in-android?

Comment: no i ill try it and tell you ..thank you for the respond

Comment: i tryed this code try {  
    set_date.setText(format.format(ca.getTime()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
} and thi works for me .. thx again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from:

```
try {  
     set_date.setText(format.format(new Date(date)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

to

```
try {  
    set_date.setText(format.format(ca.getTime()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: i ill try it and tell you if it works .. thank you for the respond