# Why is my code getting wrong date?

Tags: android

I am using this code to get current date to string, however, the date it gets is `1899-12-31` how is this possible?

```
    // save date
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        .format(new Date(0, 0, 0));
                file.writeToSD("Date: " + date.toString());
```

Comment: Don't use `Date`. Use a `Calendar` instead. If you want to know why you get that seemingly odd output, have a look at [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: Uh, why? Just use a `Calendar`. There are plenty of examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654990/how-can-i-get-current-date-in-android

Answer (score 1):

0,0,0 is the epoc -- in this case the year 1900

try date();

better take a look at the date page

Comment: what is that? where do i put that man?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve current date then use only use newDate(). Its return current millisecond

In your case you should use bellow code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
file.writeToSD("Date = " + currenDate);
```