# Change date and time format Android

Tags: java, android, android-date

I am getting date and time as `2017-01-15T21:30:05Z`  from an API. I want to change the date to `JAN 15,2017` and time to `9:30 pm` format.

Here is my code without formatting.

```
News currentNews = newsList.get(position);
String time=currentNews.getTime();
String[] parts=time.split("T");
parts[1]=parts[1].replace("Z","");

dateView.setText(parts[0]);
timeView.setText(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Such issues have been a lot.. You can SEE here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654990/how-can-i-get-current-date-in-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` object. You will need to create 1 SimpleDateFormat with initial style and 1 with desired style. Then create a Date object and parse received from API date to this object. Then print out it using the second SimpleDateFormat.

Try this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a");

try {
    Date d = sdf.parse("2017-01-15T21:30:05Z");
    System.out.println(d);                     // date in INITIAL format
    System.out.println(sdf2.format(d));        // date in DESIRED format
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,Code is working perfectly.

Comment: @priyanshugoyal Glad to hear that! Consider accepting and upvoting my answer :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use le class SimpleDateFormat to parse your String. Then, you can get a Date from it.

Here is an example if usage : [Java SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") gives timezone as IST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist)

For more details, here is the official documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html