# Two ways of getting time

Tags: java, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.currentTimeMillis() vs. new Date() vs. Calendar.getInstance().getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime)

So far I've seen two ways of getting time in Java:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

and

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I know that the latter is UNIX time, i.e. time passed from 1970...
But, when to use first and when to use second time?
Thanks.

Comment: In short - it is the same. Use System.currentTimeMillis(), it is always in UTC (w/o zone offset and dst).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the semantics of the second one (get the current time), then don't use the first one. The first one is only needed when you want to convert a specific moment of your choosing to the epoch number. Keep in mind that `currentTimeMillis` gives epoch*1000 time.