# Is this any different from just returning new System.currentTimeMillis()?

Tags: java, date

I just stumbled accross this method

```
public static Date getNowDate() {
    final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

which gets called like this:

```
getNowDate().getTime()
```

Is this any different from just calling

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

?

Comment: I found a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime

hope it helps

Regards

Comment: That `getNowDate()` method does things in an overcomplicated way - it belongs on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all much the same except for performance.

System.currentTimeMillis() is a system call so it takes around 0.1 to 0.3 micro-seconds (depending on your OS)

new Date() also creates an object, which takes only about 0.1 to 0.3 micro-seconds *more* but creates a little garbage.

Calendar.getInstance() creates an expensive set of objects and takes about **33** micro-seconds *more*.

Answer (score 3):

No difference in terms of resultant return value of long (millis)

If you wish current date, simpler way would be, You are setting the date in Calendar and retrieving it back in `getNowDate()` which can be simplify as follow

```
public static Date getNowDate() {
  return new Date();
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a difference in means of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I **don't think** there is any difference between these two, **in the form of result**, as both of them will return long values dating back from January 1st 1970 till date.

Even simply calling `Date d = new Date();` will **give you the present date** and
calling `d.getTime();` will **return its long repersentation**