# How set maximum date in datepicker dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

In my application am using date picker to set date.i want to set date picker maximum date is as today date according to system date.i don't know how to set date picker maximum date as today date.Can any one know help me to solve this problem.

**My date picker coding is:**

```
private int pYear;
private int pMonth;
private int pDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
pYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
pMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
pDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Date picker
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                pYear = year;
                pMonth = monthOfYear;
                pDay = dayOfMonth;

                e_dob.setText(new StringBuilder()
                        // to set date in editext
                        .append(pDay).append("/").append(pMonth + 1)
                        .append("/").append(pYear).append(" "));
            }
        };
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth,
                pDay);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Use [`setMaxDate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29).

For example, replace `return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay)` statement with something like this:

```
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
    return dialog;
```

Comment: Your answer deserves an upvote too ;), you show the short way!

Comment: To set max date for all api try this https://gist.github.com/Kishanjvaghela/7b8738bbb224c5f2e652

Comment: After setting the `setMaxDate` of datePicker the `setMaxDate` is always highlighted and selected, here is the [image](http://imgur.com/5WPjzcu)

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad Yes I realized that too, I found no solution yet.

Answer (score 44):

Get today's date (& time) and apply them as maximum date.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2017, 0, 1);//Year,Mounth -1,Day
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

ALSO WE MAY DO THIS (check this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime) for System.currentTimeMillis() vs Calendar method)

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(now);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now+(1000*60*60*24*7)); //After 7 Days from Now
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what is the code doing.

Comment: this is perfect and actual answer for set any maximum date

Comment: I was looking for min date this works as well. Thanks!

Comment: what is `c.set(2017, 0, 1)`? Is it the oldest date?

Answer (score 14):

You can try replacing this line:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
```

By those:

```
DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
DatePicker datePicker = dpDialog.getDatePicker();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//get the current day
datePicker.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//set the current day as the max date
return dpDialog;
```

Answer (score 12):

## Try This

I have tried too many solutions but neither them was working,After wasting my half day finally i made a solution.

> **This code simply show you a DatePickerDialog with Minimum and Maximum date,month and year,whatever you want just modify it.**

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day_of_month) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (month+1));
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day_of_month);
                        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());
                        your_edittext.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                    }
                },calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());// TODO: used to hide previous date,month and year
                calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
                dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());// TODO: used to hide future date,month and year
                dialog.show();
```

**Output:-**
Disable previous and future calendar

[image]

Comment: I'm getting error when I paste the code - getActivity() is in red. the error is "can not find symbol method getActivity()". It is suggeting to create a method or create property.

Comment: Figured it - It is the Activity from where we are calling. If the syntax of DatePickerDialog is shown in comments, it would have been helpful. Upvoting this answer

Comment: @SriramNadiminti getActivity() is a context you can use "this" if you are using in Activity and for Fragment use "getActivity()"

Comment: Thank you. How to pass the data to "MyDate", "MyMonth" and "MyYear" which are public Int variables? I have to click twice to get the setText to work

Answer (score 4):

```
private int pYear;
private int pMonth;
private int pDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

/**inside oncreate */
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         pYear= c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         pMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         pDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


 @Override
     protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
             switch (id) {
             case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                     return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                             mDateSetListener,
                             pYear, pMonth-1, pDay);
            }

             return null;
     }
     protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
             switch (id) {
             case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                     ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(pYear, pMonth-1, pDay);
                     break;
             }
     }   
     private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
         new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                         int dayOfMonth) {
                // write your code here to get the selected Date
         }
 };
```

try this it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Kotlin extension function:

```
fun EditText.transformIntoDatePicker(context: Context, format: String, maxDate: Date? = null) {
    isFocusableInTouchMode = false
    isClickable = true
    isFocusable = false

    val myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val datePickerOnDataSetListener =
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.UK)
            setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.time))
        }

    setOnClickListener {
        DatePickerDialog(
            context, datePickerOnDataSetListener, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).run {
            maxDate?.time?.also { datePicker.maxDate = it }
            show()
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

In Activity:

```
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(this, "MM/dd/yyyy")
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(this, "MM/dd/yyyy", Date())
```

In Fragments:

```
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(requireContext(), "MM/dd/yyyy")
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(requireContext(), "MM/dd/yyyy", Date())
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code directly in main method hope it will help you...

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)       
public DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog_db()
{

    DatePickerDialog pickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(),your view, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

    pickerDialog.show();

    return null;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my custom datepickerdialog

https://github.com/Redman1037/EightFoldsDatePickerDialog

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


/**
 * Created by Manohar on 14/08/2017.
 */

public class EightFoldsDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {


    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public EightFoldsDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public EightFoldsDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, themeResId);
    }

    public EightFoldsDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, listener, year, month, dayOfMonth);
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, listener, year, month, dayOfMonth);

    }

    public EightFoldsDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, int themeResId, @Nullable OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, themeResId, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, themeResId, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    public void show() {
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }


    public void setMinDate(int year, int month, int day) {

        String minDate = "" + day + "-" + getmonth(month) + "-" + year;

        try {
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(dateFormat.parse(minDate).getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setMaxDate(int year, int month, int day) {

        String maxDate = "" + day + "-" + getmonth(month) + "-" + year;
        try {
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(dateFormat.parse(maxDate).getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setTodayAsMaxDate() {

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());

    }

    public void setTodayAsMinDate() {

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());

    }


    private String getmonth(int month) {

        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                return "January";

            case 2:
                return "February";

            case 3:
                return "March";

            case 4:
                return "April";

            case 5:
                return "May";

            case 6:
                return "June";

            case 7:
                return "July";

            case 8:
                return "August";

            case 9:
                return "September";

            case 10:
                return "October";

            case 11:
                return "November";

            case 12:
                return "December";


        }
        return "January";

    }

}
```

## Usage

Copy EightFoldsDatePickerDialog.java to your project

```
EightFoldsDatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new EightFoldsDatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
              //Do something with date
                Toast.makeText(this, "Year "+year+" month "+month+" day "+dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        },year,month,day);   // give any  year , month , day values, this will be opened by default in dialog

        datePickerDialog.setMinDate(2017,8,7); //arguments are   year , month , date (use for setting custom min date)
        datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(2017,8,25);  //arguments are   year , month , date (use for setting custom max date)

       // datePickerDialog.setTodayAsMinDate();   // sets today's date as min date
       // datePickerDialog.setTodayAsMaxDate();    // sets today's date as max date

        datePickerDialog.show();
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

private void selectDOB() {

```
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            strDateOfBirth = (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth + "-" + year;

            //********************** check and set date with append 0 at starting***************************
            if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
                strNewDay = "0" + dayOfMonth;
            } else {
                strNewDay = dayOfMonth + "";
            }
            if (month + 1 < 10) {
                strNewMonth = "0" + (month + 1);
            } else {
                strNewMonth = (month + 1) + "";
            }

            Log.e("strnewDay *****************", strNewDay + "");
            Log.e("strNewMonth *****************", strNewMonth + "");

            //    etDateOfBirth.setText(dayOfMonth + " / " + (month + 1) + " / " + year);
            etDateOfBirth.setText(strNewDay + " / " + strNewMonth + " / " + year);

            Log.e("strDateOfBirth *******************", strDateOfBirth + "");

        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    datePickerDialog.show();

    //*************** input date of birth must be greater than or equal to 18 ************************************

    Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
    maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
    maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear - 18);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTimeInMillis());

    //*************** input date of birth must be less than today date ************************************
    //   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation what you've done here and how it's different to the original code? You also probably don't want the commented out code or error logs.

Comment: In this user can set date according to the age criteria needed in his application.
Like user can only set the age aboe 18 years then he could use this code .

Comment: getInstance is API30. What if I want to use API 25 and below?

Answer (score 1):

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    //To set make max 7days date selection on current year and month
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate((cal.getTimeInMillis())+(1000*60*60*24*6));

    datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Custom date picker](https://gist.github.com/Kishanjvaghela/7b8738bbb224c5f2e652), that is work for all api levels.

```
public class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

    int maxYear;
    int maxMonth;
    int maxDay;

    public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    public void setMaxDate(long maxDate) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        } else {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeInMillis(maxDate);
            maxYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            maxMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            maxDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            super.onDateChanged(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        } else {
            if (year > maxYear)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

            if (monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

            if (dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
        }
    }
```

set max date

```
final CustomDatePickerDialog pickerDialog = new CustomDatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
        myDateListener, year, month, day);
pickerDialog.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
pickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by following

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

dp.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```