# How to show the Calender of only one year from current date in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker, android-date, android-dateutils

I want that the calender show user only one year date and rest will be disabled for the past it is working fine .But now i want to make so that the user can select only one year calender from current date.here is my code .Please suggest me the changes.

```
textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

                }
            });


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog _date =   new DatePickerDialog(this, date,myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {   
                    if (year < now.get(Calendar.YEAR))

                        view.updateDate(myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (monthOfYear < now.get(Calendar.MONTH) && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (dayOfMonth < now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR) && 
                            monthOfYear == now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                        }
            };
            return _date;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the current date. then increase the year value by one. then use setMaxDate function as [How set maximum date in datepicker dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android) question shows.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a calender as below instead of calling Calender.getInstance();

Calendar minCal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

Comment: Actually i want to show the calender of one year from the current date

Answer (score 0):

Use `setMinDate()` and `setMaxDate()` on the `DatePicker`. You can access it from your `DatePickerDialog` with `getDatePicker()` (requires API level 11).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html