# Restrict Endate to go to previous date of StartDate

Tags: android

I have two dates i.e Startdate and Enddate.I am using DatePickerDialog.
Suppose my Startdate is 1-3-2014 then I want to restrict Enddate going to previous date of Startdate.

Comment: check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android

Comment: @Sandeep, try below solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: I am Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple just use it like this.

```
if (DueDate.before(AssignDate))
{
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderDate = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Assignment_Create_Ext_DB.this);
                alertDialogBuilderDate.setTitle("Date assigning issue");
                alertDialogBuilderDate
                        .setMessage(
                                "Due date can not be equal or less then the Assign date")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                alertDialogBuilderDate.show();
}
else
{
  // use your coding
}
```

or same like this also you can check

```
if (DueDate.after(AssignDate))
{

  // use your coding
}
else
{
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderDate = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Assignment_Create_Ext_DB.this);
                alertDialogBuilderDate.setTitle("Date assigning issue");
                alertDialogBuilderDate
                        .setMessage(
                                "Due date can not be equal or less then the Assign date")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                alertDialogBuilderDate.show();
}
```

Difference is just `before` and `after` keyword.

Here `duedate` and `assigndate` both are your `Calendar` variable.