# Fix DatePickerDialog setMaxDate and setMinDate on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

There's a bug on Android L that even if a min and max date is set, user can still select disabled dates.

[image: Screenshot]

I've already filed an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=103263&can=1&q=DatePickerDialog&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), but I'm wondering is there's any solution to fix this before next android system update?

Comment: Been looking around myself, no solution has presented itself.

Comment: you can compare it with current system date and put some condition based on that. I used this as my workaround

Comment: Hi, You can refer this [LINK](https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-datepickerdialog-set-max-date.html). I know is not for lollipop, but I have recently worked on this for Lollipop. You have to just do like `DatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(newCalendar.getTimeInMillis());` for setting max date to current date.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android) the perfect answer for you. Please, Refer **ozbek's** answer. Code is like below, In case if above link will get break in future.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

Do same for `setminDate()`.

Enjoy..!