# Setting min Date in Date Picker created using dialog fragments

Tags: android, datepicker

I created my date picker using this link [Date Picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker)

**I know we can use setMinDate() method** to set Minimum date but I don't understand how to do it if we implement date picker the way it is provided in the link.
I didn't find any way of doing it while using this method.
Date Picker code

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        tv_date= (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        tv_date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
                .append(month+1).append("-").append(year));
        date=tv_date.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android

Comment: @Raghunandan first check the link I provided. Implementation way is different in my case

Comment: Look @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#getDatePicker().  In onCreateDialog you return a Datepicker dialog

Comment: I tried that but then gives an error that method return types are different

Comment: posy your code of what you have tried

Comment: Method requires dialog but when add getDialog line with return statement it starts returning void

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100545/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-vivek-mishra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in this link : [DatePicker#setMinDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)) , We need to get date picker object to set min or max date in the picker dialog.

See code snippet given below, which will solve your issue:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, this, year, month, day);

        //set min date (ex. current date and time) - pass your custom date and time in milliseconds
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        //set max date
        //dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate);

        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener,    year, month, day);  
DatePicker dp = d.getDatePicker(); 
dp.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
return d;
```