# Set limit to maximum date on DatePicker in Android

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar

I'm working on a form to input user info. There's an `EditText` to set the date of birth. tapping on it opens a `DatePickerDialogue`. I want to set limit on the date to current date so that user cannot select date from the future.

Here's my Code:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd;
Edittext etDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
etDOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(ActivityCustomerInfo.this,dpd,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
dpd=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
String month = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
                etDOB.setText(new StringBuilder().append((month)+" ").append((dayOfMonth)+", ").append(year));
            }
        };
```

I know a function setMaxDate() but cannot understand how to apply it to my code.

[I followed the answers here but the code doesn't seem to match with mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android)

Comment: Take a look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16749501/5225620
 just create a reference to your DatePickerDialog so you can call the getDatePicker() method, then use the setmaxDate().

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm sorry to sound dumb but I'm beginner to android. @Rafael

Comment: Where you're creating your new DatePickerDialog inside your onClick method, try this `DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(ActivityCustomerInfo.this,dpd,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());

dialog.show();`

Comment: If you still having trouble here is the code more clean: https://gist.github.com/faelmorais/d507cc655487843fda36124c48b641d5

Comment: thank you for making it easier to understand @Rafael. solved the problem