# How to set maxDate With this Code?

Tags: android

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
        }

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                                  int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                et.setText( selectedYear + "-" + (selectedMonth + 1) + "-"
                        + selectedDay);
               Datecal=et.getText().toString();
            }
        };
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set maximum date in datepicker dialog in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setMaxDate()`.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
    return dialog;
```