# Android: How to disable future days on DatePickerFragment

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I created a datepicker using `DatePickerFragment` in android.

Below is my code,

```
@OnClick(R.id.add_info_food_date_edit)
public void setDate() {

    DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    datePickerFragment.setCallbackListener(new DatePickerFragment.onDatePickerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataSet(int year, int month, int day) {

            int currentMonth = 0;

            if (month == 0) {
                currentMonth = 1;
            } else if (month == 1) {
                currentMonth = 2;
            } else if (month == 2) {
                currentMonth = 3;
            } else if (month == 3) {
                currentMonth = 4;
            } else if (month == 4) {
                currentMonth = 5;
            } else if (month == 5) {
                currentMonth = 6;
            } else if (month == 6) {
                currentMonth = 7;
            } else if (month == 7) {
                currentMonth = 8;
            } else if (month == 8) {
                currentMonth = 9;
            } else if (month == 9) {
                currentMonth = 10;
            } else if (month == 10) {
                currentMonth = 11;
            } else if (month == 11) {
                currentMonth = 12;
            } else if (month == 12) {

            }

            dateEditText.setText(day + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + year);
        }
    });

    DialogFragment datePicker = datePickerFragment;

    datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Now I want to disable future days in this datepicker without destroying this code . Still I haven't any good thought about the change. How can I accomplish this.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set maximum date in datepicker dialog in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android)

Comment: @RahulSharma : Please look at the code . This code is difference.

Answer (score 1):

setMaxDate as current date like this

```
datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

updated

```
DialogFragment newFragment = datePickerFragment;
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();     // commits the show method from above
DatePickerDialog dialog = (DatePickerDialog) newFragment.getDialog();
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.getDatePicker();
Date date = new Date();
datePicker.setMaxDate(date.getTime());
```

Comment: I can't see any `getDatePicker` available for `DialogFragment`. My min SDK version is 15 and target is 24