# How to setMax Date Dialog Picker still show value

Tags: android

[Show Date Dialog Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeUJt.png)

Dear All.
I'm testing with Date Picker Dialog, when I setMax it'll show look like image.
But, now I would like to show day left of the month.
For example, I set max which is 20/07/2017, it only show the first day of next month(01/08/2017), it hide days from 21/07 - 30/07.
Can everyone help me.
Thank you so much!

And this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }
            }, year, month, day);
            //dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Date will there but user, won't be able to select. This is a behavior of default DatePicker widget.

Comment: Yes, I needn't click there, I only need show

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set maximum date in datepicker dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try below code:

```
      @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    public SelectDateFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog, this, yy, mm, dd);
        else
            datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this, this, yy, mm, dd);

        Calendar maxDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        maxDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

     // here you are adding maxdate 
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {

       //  get the date here and use it

    }
}
```

and here's how you can use the above class

- Declare an object first

  ```
   DialogFragment dateFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
  ```
- Show it on click of some button or something

  ```
   dateFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
  ```

Comment: Thanking about your anwser, if you use maxDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); it'll be show, but now I would like you can not onclick into that, can you help me?

Comment: can you elaborate your que, otherwise set the date in max date whatever you want.

Comment: and after that, you won't be able to click on any date from and after max date