# How to set maximum date and minmum date in date picker dialog

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, datepickerdialog

I would like to make the calendar show particular month and I would like to define range of allowed dates in calendar

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this.OnToDateSet, today.Year, today.Month - 1, today.Day);
dateDialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.Millisecond;
dateDialog.DatePicker.MinDate = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month - 2, today.Day).Millisecond;
dateDialog.Show();
```

this is what I get in return ... it shows the wrong year & month when it appears

if I comment out maxdate and mindate then calendar opens at right year and month

[image]

Somebody please clarify

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set maximum date in datepicker dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android)

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but with other frameworks I had to write a check after the date was picked, and if it was outside of the bounds I wouldn't let them save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is what I get in return ... it shows the wrong year & month when it appears
>
> if I comment out maxdate and mindate then calendar opens at right year and month

If you debug your codes, you will find `DateTime.Today.Millisecond` and `new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month - 2, today.Day).Millisecond` returns 0. This is where things went wrong. In Xamarin, if you want to get the Millisecond, you need to do a DateTime offset:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, today.Year, today.Month - 1, today.Day);
//DateTime.MinValue isn't 1970/01/01 so we need to create a min date manually
double maxSeconds = (DateTime.Today - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
double minSeconds = (new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month - 2, today.Day) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
dateDialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = (long)maxSeconds;
dateDialog.DatePicker.MinDate = (long)minSeconds;
dateDialog.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Can you please explain me .. .about the DateTimeOffiset please ? Its confusing to me

Comment: inorder to make calendar show the current month ... I have to subtract a month .. which is not right ? please see `DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this.OnToDateSet, today.Year, today.Month - 1, today.Day);`

Comment: reducing one month to get the calendar to show current month doesn't make sense to me...does the month start from 0 or something