# Set Max Date (Date Picker)

Tags: java, android

I want to add a upper limit to my date picker (spinner). The max date should be "today". I tried to add this line of code but then my app crashes:

```
dpDate.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

Here's the whole code, can anybody see what's wrong? :)

```
 addToCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity4.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_call,null);



            final DatePicker dpDate = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dpDate);
            dpDate.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime()); //this makes the app crash



            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();


            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try this : `dpDate.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());`

Comment: I got "cannot resolve method "getDatePicker()', maybe only works for DatePickerDialog?

Comment: can you add the logs what you are getting after app crashes ?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dex, PID: 18439
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.DatePicker.setMaxDate(long)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dex.Activity4$4$override.onClick(Activity4.java:149)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16749361/2867656

Answer (score 0):

You must add `setMaxDate` on `onCreateDialog` method like below

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme,null,year,month,day);

        //set max date
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Okay I am not using DatePickerDialog, only a DatePicker,  inside a custom Alert Dialog but thanks will try to apply what you wrote

Comment: why do you do that? why do you not use DatePickerDialog and and customize it ?

Comment: That's maybe a better way to do it! :D