# Datepicker in Class Activity

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using the following code in the activity ApplyLeave. I would like to pick the date and save the date, month and year to public int variables.

```
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(ApplyLeave.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day_of_month) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (month)); //add +1 for next month calendar
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day_of_month);
                    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());
                    dtTmp = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

                }
            },calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//used to hide previous date,month and year
            calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
            //dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//used to hide future date,month and year
            dialog.show();
            String[] selTmp = dtTmp.split("/");

            selBdate = Integer.parseInt(selTmp[0]);
            selBmonth = Integer.parseInt(selTmp[1]);
            selByear = Integer.parseInt(selTmp[2]);
            stDt = MyUtility.getJulianDay(selByear, selBmonth, selBdate, ApplyLeave.this);
            eBegin.setText(dtTmp);
```

I get the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'java.lang.String[]
> java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at Line "String[] selTmp = dtTmp.split("/");

If I comment this line and the three following, the date gets picked up, but need to click twice to get the correct date set.

The datepicker code is taken from [Answer by @Sunil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android/46441581?noredirect=1#comment112276801_46441581).

Comment: `dtTmp` is null because you have written it synchronously . Better move it inside `onDateSet`..

Comment: I have moved all the four lines and placed after dtTmp declaration. Still it is null. Now it reads dtTmp = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
                        String[] selTmp = dtTmp.split("/");

                        selBdate = Integer.parseInt(selTmp[0]);
                        selBmonth = Integer.parseInt(selTmp[1]);
                        selByear = Integer.parseInt(selTmp[2]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        TextView textView;
        Button txt_open_date_picker;
        int yy,mm,dd;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
            txt_open_date_picker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.txt_open_date_picker);
    
            txt_open_date_picker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.this,
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            textView.setText(date);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Have changed it as datepicker class and added necessary xml. How can I call this from another class as I need to pick the date several times in my app.

Comment: follow this link - [https://www.journaldev.com/9976/android-date-time-picker-dialog]

Answer (score 0):

try this it's working for me

```
     final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity_five.this,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    
                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    
                                    Date date = new Date(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    
                                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                                    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                    // String cdate = formatter.format(date);
                                    String strDate = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    
                                     
                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    
//for set max value in date
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Where should I keep this code - within the onclicklistener? or in Oncreate section. Pl guide. When I kept it in the OnClickListener, I have to click twice to get the date set. First time I'm not getting the date to this variable strDate.