# Which one is the best way to get timestamp in android in long format?

Tags: android, android-studio, datetime, timestamp

I searched a lot I found some solutions for that and got confused to select which method to use to get a timestamp in android and which one is the best.

#### found

1. Get by using the android Calendar

`Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`

2. By using the Date

`new Date().getTime()`

3. By using System

`Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;`

`String ts = tsLong.toString();`

Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is obviously the most efficient since it does not even create an object, but `new Date()` is really just a thin wrapper about a long, so it is not far behind. `Calendar`, on the other hand, is relatively slow and very complex, since it has to deal with the considerable complexity and all the oddities that are inherent to dates and times (leap years, daylight savings, timezones, etc.).

It's generally a good idea to deal only with long timestamps or Date objects within your application, and only use Calendar when you actually need to perform date/time calculations or to format dates for displaying them to the user. If you have to do a lot of this, using Joda Time is probably a good idea, for the cleaner interface and better performance.

for full discussion [please check the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime)